# What do MRC and WI Abbreviations Mean in Virginia Marriages of the Northern Neck?

Tags: sources, 17th-century, virginia, abbreviations

I have a marriage entry I found in this book on Ancestry:

> Virginia, Marriages of the Northern Neck of Virginia, 1649-1800; [Ancestry Record 5063 #14673](https://prf.hn/click/camref:1011l4xx5/type:cpc/destination:https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=1&db=5063&h=14673); Name: Elizabeth Wilson; Marriage Date: Abt 1697; Spouse Name: Edward Moseley; Marriage Location: Virginia, United States. [Image](https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/5063/gpc_marriedwellandoften-0266) Quote Page 252: Moseley, Edward & Wilson, Elizabeth; bef. 2 Mar 1697/98; bride was a dau. of Elias Wilson the Elder (died Richmond County 1699/1700); (Richmond County Order Book 3:331; WI 1699–1709:f10r; MRC:139)

The book has a list of abbreviations [starting here](https://www.ancestry.com/imageviewer/collections/5063/images/gpc_marriedwellandoften-0425). But it omits `WI` and `MRC`, so I'm wondering what those stand for?

Also where it reads `WI 1699–1709:f10r` what does `f10r` stand for?

Comment: I’m guessing “f10r” means “folio 10, recto”, ie the front side of page 10.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recto_and_verso).  Hopefully someone more authoritative can confirm.

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks, I'm also still wondering what `WI` stands for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prior section has another set of abbreviations for books:

> `MRC` Marriages of Richmond County Virginia 1668–1853 by George H. S. King.